# Reversing a string in C not working

Tags: c

I have been working on a program that reverses a string from a user. 
I have another program that does something very similar, just without the user input. Yet the former doesn't want to set the values of the second string to the first. Any and all help is appreciated!

also i apologize for my formatting, this is my first time using this forum

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char original[8], new[8];
int i = 0, t = 8;

void main(){

    printf("Enter your string here: ");
    scanf("%s", &original);

    for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++, t--){
        printf("%c\n", original[i]);
        new[t] = original[i];
    }

    printf("Your new string is %s\n", new);
}
```

Comment: paste your complete code please

Comment: where have you initialized `t` and why `i<=8`?

Comment: Where are `new` and `original` declared? And in what way is it "not working"? Prints garbage? Prints nothing? segfaults? Only reverses some of the string? You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your input, and actual output (expected output will be obvious so that can be omitted). There's not enough here for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work property

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  char str[50],temp;
  int i,j,len;
  puts("enter a string");
  gets(str);
  len=strlen(str);
  /* reverse the string*/
  for(i=0,j=len-1; i<j; i++,j--)
  {
     temp = str[i];
     str[i] = str[j];
     str[j] = temp;
  }
  printf("Reverse string is %s",str);
}
```

Here I had use only one array and reversed the string it uses less memory and easy to understand.
Hope this works.kudos.

Comment: Supplying working code with no explanation does not answer the question of why the original code did not work.

Comment: this is the most helpful response by far, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Eric Postpischil thanks I'm new over here I will keep this in mind

Answer (score -1):

Your code is flawed. The arrays you are iterating are of size 8, and in C it starts from 0, so when you mention the size of array as 8 it means the subscript 7 is the end of the array.
In your case you must actually input string of length 8 and not less than that.
Because when you are printing the array the new will always take it from &new[0] which is the base address, which has nothing. However assuming that your input string will be exactly 8 bytes following is the rectified code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>  
    char original[8], new[8];
    int i = 0, t = 7;
    void main(){
        printf("Enter your string here: ");
        scanf("%s", &original);
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++, t--){
        printf("%c\n", original[i]);
        new[t] = original[i];
        }
        printf("Your new string is %s\n", new);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you add the string terminator?

Comment: You could increment the array size to 9 for original and new and then iterate it till 9 instead of 8 as shown above. Infact the best thing to do is use memset at the beginning of main for new ie memset(new,0,9), for this you include string.h and then rest remains the same